# disassemble elf sectionless files

Tags: disassembly

Follower this [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/disassemble-elf-file-created-by-msfvenom/13833) (thanks "Igor Skochinsky")

when use
`objdump -b binary ...` we can't see correct disassemble in section-less `elf` file

Because `objdump` disassemble Header and code and we see false disassemble code.

What better way to do it right there?

Comment: Have you considered using a full-blown disassembler product? Most will support sectionless elf files out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write mini `ruby` script for dump DATA from `EP` to `end` of file and save it to another file

then we can disassemble it with `objdump -b binary ..` very nice

```
$ 
$ objdump -b binary -m i386 -D RAW
```

this script read ELF file and find `endian` mode (`little` or `Big`) then find `EP` and dump it

in this picture we can see difference between this command's

[image]

we can set and change `EP` from `-E` , and `length` data of dump from `-l "end-1"` or set start of dump without calculate `EP` with `-s` command

[downlaod and fork me][2]